# RF controlled switch turns on first load on power restore

Tags: switch, light-fixture

I have installed a 3 channel RF remote controlled switch in my house that I recently bought (Image attached below)

I have made the connections as follows

- Live Wire : Live wire
- 2 x Ground : Ground
- Output 1 : Load 1
- Output 2 : Load 2
- Output 3 : Load 3

Everything works properly in normal conditions, but after power-cut when the power is restored, 1st load gets turned on by itself.

I have 2 of these RF switches installed at 2 different rooms and both behave in the same manner.

How can I avoid this unexpected behavior?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: @isherwood I'm disagreeing with you when you said the source is irrelevant.  I think it's the crux.    Now... I see a yellow wire which might be green/yellow, but I see no second ground.  I see a blue and white either of which might be neutral. **Neutral is not ground**. This thing needs a neutral, surely.  Also is it made for mains power or 12/24VDC?

Comment: If this behavior is built into the device, the only way to change it would be to alter the device.  Modifying the device to work as you'd like, is beyond the scope of this site.  Unfortunately, the device manufacturer is likely the only one that can answer this, and it sounds like they're nowhere to be found.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off topic because it's about modifying the designed behavior of a device, not do-it-yourself home improvement.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are saying is that the devices have a default setting of "normally on" after a power loss. There might be a way to change this. A quick call to the manufacturer could answer your question.

Comment: There is no way I can reach the manufacturer, also no luck in contacting  the seller.

Comment: I got a lead from YouTube comments as follows
"Major design problem on all models of this design: at start-up, the relay is powered! So the device to be ordered is immediately powered!
On a two-channel module, this known anomaly is almost bypassed by the written procedure on the object: "1. Connect the power supply with the A / 1 ON ... This does not prevent a short action of the relay"

but I am not sure what does this means, I tried contacting the this guy, but no reply as for now. 
Can you help me in understaning the above comment, atleast whether it is a solution or not.

Thanks